# how to get masterkey and consequent wallet keys from root seed?

Tags: private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, bip

So basically i am trying to create my own crypto wallet application in python, i have generated the random entropy, calculated the checksum, generated the 12 words and then  generated the root seed using pbkdf2, but after generating the seed I'm kinda lost, i dont know how i can generate the master key and the chaincode, and then generating the public and private keys, lets put for example i have this root seed `1f8c67bc66355f62f6c63752803599cc6e4a05eac6dd63e05e858329f3656ed3c868bd428a4218b4eb92e0fe5e774874c4ab270b8d1377ddc0aea6a797682342`
what should i do with it to generate the master private key and then the following child public/private keys? thanks, i'm very new to this in general so sorry if there is any issue with my question

Answer (score 0):

Read BIP32 and BIP44. Also learnmeabitcoin.com under HD Wallets and Derivation Paths.

Walk through the open source software implementations step by step.

As a user, Bitcoin Explorer (bx) examples, iancoleman's site code, bitaddress

generate wallets from the command line, bash scripts using Bitcoin Bash Tools etc.

Have a thorough understanding of what these tools are doing as a user before trying to replicate it as a coder

Comment: i read it a few times but i still didnt understand at all, maybe im doing something wrong ... also i dont want to generate wallets from the command line or any bash scripts i want to create an python code from scratch that does it, i have already generated the seed what i need now is to generate the chain code and the master private key but i cant figure out exactly how i can generate those...

Comment: @user132741 If you can be more specific, people will be more able to help. Can you say exactly which line in BIP32 is holding you up the most?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick i am having trouble to understand this topic of the BIP32 documentation: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#Master_key_generation ,
my problem is i dont know what to do after hashing the entropy to get the master seed,
i dont know exactly how to be more clear but lets give an example of this seed i generated just now `d213b3de1949e716b2e5fb96ae62efa0c27843debf4372e8840ebc7f87024f6cb10126e51bbfecd362ac21105edef4c799b09c973d05a5b566b5173e185e7927`
what i do exactly with it to generate the master private key ?

Comment: Do you have [a library that implements HMAC-SHA512](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+hmac+sha256)?